# Detect installed related applications in Flutter web

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a Flutter app running on iOS and Android. Now I want to run it on the web and if the user does not have it on a device, suggest the user to install the app from the store.
How can I detect any related app installed on the device or not?

I do not find any useful solution to this.